# What's the difference between form button-link and js button-link?

Tags: javascript, html, web, button, request

What's the difference between these two ways to turn button into a link:

```
<form method="GET" action="example.com">                
<button type="submit">button text</button>
</form>
```

VS

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'example.com';">button text</button>
```

It has the same effect but is there any flaws of usage one of ways?

Comment: well witch "onclick" you activate an javascript, GET is a methode to pass variables from one site to an other , its needed e.g PHP scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First One :**

```
<form method="GET" action="example.com">                
<button type="submit">button text</button>
</form>
```

Advantage :

1. you can send query string data prams into url in form  Fields.
2. complex link can be formed easily and with sending complex data to Action url.

Disadvantage :

1. None of disadvantage it based on your choice.
2. No Dynamic link can be generate Action="" attribute not support java script code.

**Second One :**

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'example.com';">button text</button>
```

Advantage :

1. you can generate link based on dynamically value changes.

   location.href = 'example.com'+document.getElementById('otherInput').value;

Disadvantage :

1. you can't be send more data in this way this only used as basic usage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The first one will go to the `action` URL with all the form input that is inside the form as GET parameters.

The 2nd one is a javascript event based action, it only goes to the URL with the parameters that you specify.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But maybe there are some scenarios where these ways have different result?